# node js forms (caolan) bootstrap compatible

Tags: node.js, express

How can I wrap widgets in [forms](https://github.com/caolan/forms) module? [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms) requires the input elements must be wrapped inside a `<div class="controls">`.

For the label and field classes, I have already acheived the required stracture by

```
var sport_form = forms.create({
    title: fields.string({required: true
        , widget: widgets.text({classes: ['not_working']})
        , errorAfterField: true
        , cssClasses: {
            label: ['control-label'],
            field: ['control-group'],
        }
    }),
    description: fields.string({errorAfterField: true}),
    date: fields.date({widget: widgets.date(), required: true, errorAfterField: true})
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I just now committed a tutorial to the forms project on github. Here is the link https://github.com/caolan/forms#bootstrap-compatible-output

Enjoy :)